# Understanding node.js callbacks 2.0

Tags: node.js, callback

I know this question has been asked 1000 times but so far I am not able to put it into the mental context that satisfies my understanding of it. I understand what callbacks are and why. I also understand that by the time a value is returned to the calling function, the program has moved on with its life.  Here are my files.

in file myModule.js

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    f: function(val, callback){
        var ext = val[3];
        var dir = val[2];
        fs.readdir(dir, function(err,path,files){
        var count = path.length;
        var files = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < count; x++){
            if(path[x].toString().split('.')[1]){
                if(path[x].toString().split('.')[1] == ext) files.push(path[x]);
                }
            }
        callback(files);

           });

       }

};
```

and server.js that is requiring myModule...

```
'use strict'

var fs = require('fs');
var myMod = require('./myModule');
var dMod = require('./dMod');
var val = process.argv;
var r = myMod.f(val, function(rtn, callback){
    if(rtn){
        for(r in rtn) console.log(rtn[r]);
        }

    });
// part where I say "Hey you must wait here until we get rtn because we need him!"
console.log(r)
```

Am I correct in my understanding that **rtn** is essentially trapped inside the callback and any future function that I want to execute that requires **rtn** will have to be nested (unless I use async) inside the callback, and so on?

Comment: Will appreciate your feedback here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546846/callback-confusion-and-collecting-data-in-node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct. The scope of `rtn` is within that callback. The only other way to pass the value without nesting is to call an external callback with the value. Example:

```
function myCallback(rtn) {
  // use `rtn` here
}

myMod.f(val, function(rtn, callback){
  if (rtn) {
    for(r in rtn) console.log(rtn[r]);
  }
  myCallback(rtn);
});
```